# No response while pressing on a button from mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have responsive website, while pressing on one of the buttons :

```
<div class="button">
    <input src="Images/TransparenImgButt.PNG" 
        onclick="if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') 
            Page_ClientValidate('');" 
        name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$OrderNewCard" type="image"
        id="OrderNewCard" runat="server" class=" NewCardPic"
     /> 
</div>
```

I don't get the page I need (which I get from the web) what I need to change here? 
Thank you for any help

Comment: did you mean its working on web but not on mobile?

Comment: do you have same button on all screens ?

Comment: @RaiTalhaRehman Yes I have same button on all screen. working on web but not on mobile. thanks

Comment: you are testing on real device or on browser?

Comment: @RaiTalhaRehman both

Comment: on what screen size it start not responding

Comment: @RaiTalhaRehman on ipad yes iphone no

Comment: can i see your app? is it deployed on any platform or on localhost?

Comment: @RaiTalhaRehman yes sure. can you send an email?